# Is finally "out of scope" in a try/catch block

Tags: scala, try-catch-finally

Is there a way to access val's created in a try/catch block within the finally block ? or is the finally block out of scope.

```
def myTryCatch: Either[Exception, String] = {
  try {
    val w = runOrFailWithException("Please work...")
    Right(w)
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      Left(ex)
    }
  }
  finally {
    // How do I get access to Left or Right in my finally block.
    // This does not work
    _ match {
      case Right(_) =>
      case Left(_) =>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't, finally can only see stuff declared out of the try/catch scope, not inside of it.

Answer (score 12):

Why do you need to do this in the `finally` block? Since a `try/catch` is an expression, you can match on its value:

```
try {
  val w = runOrFailWithException("Please work...")
  Right(w)
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => Left(ex)
} match {
  case Right(_) =>
  case Left(_) =>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working very well. Of course, I don't need `finally` here. - Java is still somewhere in the back of my head.

Comment: Actually you event don't need a match ;) just do what you want with values inside try and catch clauses and then "return" them )

Comment: If Java's still in the back of your head you must know that the scope rules for try..catch..finally are the same in Java.